# AVERAGEIF with INDEX and condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Why does this return #VALUE! when I use AVERAGEIF?

```
=AVERAGEIF(INDEX((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*(A10:Z10),1,0),"<>0")
```

When I use `=SUM(INDEX((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*(A10:Z10),1,0))`
it works fine.

```
=average(INDEX((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*(A10:Z10),1,0))
```

also works, but the problem is it counts all the zeros, that's why I tried AVERAGEIF.

I would like to get the average using the INDEX function, not array formulas or SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

*You can use any of these array (CSE) formula:*

```
{=AVERAGE(IF((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2),A10:Z10))}

{=SUM((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*A10:Z10)/SUM(IF(YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2,1))}

{=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*(A10:Z10)) /(SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*1))}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, I tried to avoid array formulas.

Comment: @user1754501,, Array formula is the demand of the situation,, since the formula has to the check Month from available Dates in Range,, are more than one,, and formula need to check one  by one ,,, so you can't avoid an Array formula,,, *try 3 rd one it works  both as an Array and non Array* !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AVERAGEIF only operates on ranges, not arrays. Why I'm not sure, but it may be related to how the evaluation criteria are being used as text.

1. CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER might work to eliminate the #VALUE! error but the answer might still be wrong.
2. You could spare a row and place the array answer in multiple cells with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER as INDEX((YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2)*(A10:Z10),1,0) - then operate the AVERAGEIF on the range.
3. Alternatively have a look at the AGGREGATE function, which can be used as an AVERAGE function (function #1) but with options to ignore certain errors. If you do INDEX((A10:Z10)/(YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2),1,0) it will generate #DIV/0 errors to ignore.
4. Since sum is working, could you devised a way to implement you own average?

Comment: #3 is interesting, but for some reason 'AGGREGATE(1,6,INDEX(...' produces #VALUE! Besides, the formula becomes somewhat convoluted, hard to interpret for an outsider. #4 will involve an ugly COUNTIFS with ">date(...  <date(... Seems like the AVERAGE(IF... array formula is the best way, after all.

Comment: AVERAGE(IF... indeed. Array formulas for the win! Why were you trying to shy away from them? BTW, I found out the reason for #VALUE! errors from AGGREGATE. AGGREGATE only works on vertical data not horizontal data (and doesn't like transpose either) . So you first have to put your horizontal array in say A11:A34 like this {=TRANSPOSE(INDEX((A10:Z10)/(YEAR(A1:Z1)=A2),1,0))} and then call AGGREGATE from the range instead of the array =AGGREGATE(1,6,A11:A34). I guess if you really wanted an array formula free method, you could transpose your year filter vector manually to a

Comment: I just don't like them arrays)